# issue using itext7 htmltopdf converter The "Property.Font" property must be a PdfFont object in this context

Tags: java, html, css, parsing, itext7

I have a OL>Li which has a custom counter for lower alpha followed by ).
When I run HtmlConverter.convertToPdf it converts but below error is printed for every <li> under <ol>
Error :  The "Property.Font" property must be a PdfFont object in this context

Could some one help with this ?

```
ol {
    counter-reset: list;
}
ol > li {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}
ol > li:before {
    counter-increment: list;
    content: counter(list, lower-alpha) ") ";
    position: absolute;
    left: -1.4em;
}
<ol>
    <li>Number 1</li>
    <li>Number 2</li>
    <li>Number 3</li>
</ol>


HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(htmlfilepath,pdfdestination)
```

I tried adding font using ConverterProperties but error still persist